# Taking 2 pictures instantly - crashes the app

Tags: android, crash, camera, surfaceview, image

The app crashes when I take 2 pictures fast one after the other. How can I prevent the crash?
**Note:** I can take a couple of pictures but the delta time between taking pictures has to be around 500 milliseconds.
This

Here's the logcat:

```
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3063)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3058)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    ... 11 more
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:948)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:893)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    at com.inturnex.safecam.MainActivity.TakePicture(MainActivity.java:134)
07-07 23:51:31.676: E/AndroidRuntime(10799):    ... 14 more
```

Here's the code:

```
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_pick);
    m_surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    m_surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    m_camera = Camera.open();

    m_numOfCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_numOfCamera; ++i) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            m_defaultCameraId = i;
            m_currentCamera = m_defaultCameraId;
        }       
    }
    photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(this, dbHelper);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(m_camera != null){
    m_camera.stopPreview();
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(m_camera != null){
    m_camera.startPreview();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(m_camera != null){
    m_camera.release();
    }
}


public void TakePicture(View v) throws InterruptedException
{
    Log.d(Global.TAG,"In TakePicture");
    m_camera.takePicture(null, null, photoHandler);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int format, int w, int h) {
    m_surfaceWidth = w;
    m_surfaceHeight = h;
    Camera.Parameters params = m_camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size selected = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, w, h);

    params.setPreviewSize(selected.width,  selected.height);


    m_camera.setParameters(params);
    setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, m_currentCamera, m_camera);

    m_camera.startPreview();    
}
static int degrees = 0;
private static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }


public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    try {
        m_camera.setPreviewDisplay(m_surfaceView.getHolder());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {


    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null)
        return null;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be worth it but I would point out that in theory, it is not possible to use hardware in this way.
When you're trying to take the second photo, the hardware is still being used to take the first one and because of this, the program doesn't know where to go so it crashes.

Just thought that I would point this factor out, although I might get downvoted for this..

Comment: I see, so do you have any idea what could be the reason for that? the onPictureTaken is never called when I take 2 pictures instantly..